# Resolve Wildcard type in @Override implementation of an interface

Tags: java

I've been doing some reading on Wildcards in Java, but I can't figure out how you would resolve a Collection's Wildcard type in the implementation of an interface method declaration. You could technically discover the type by examining one of the objects in the Collection, but that won't allow you to resolve the type in the Collection and it fails if the Collection is empty.

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    void addAThing(Object thing);
    void addAListOfThings(Collection< ?> things);
}

public class SomeInterfaceImplementation implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public void addAThing(Object thing) {
        if (thing instanceof Foo) {
            /* thing has been discovered to be of type Foo
            so now it can be assigned to an explicit Foo object */
            Foo fooThing = (Foo) thing;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addAListOfThings(Collection< ?> things) {
        //this fails if things is empty
        if (things.toArray()[0] instanceof Foo) {
            /* things type has been discovered(maybe) to be of type Foo
            but now we are unable cast without an unchecked cast exception */
            Collection<Foo> fooThings = (Collection<Foo>) things;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a proper method I'm unaware of for doing this?

Comment: No, due to type erasure, there is no way to recover the original type at runtime.  Even your suggestion won't work, because a `List<Object>` could very well have a `String` as its first element and an `Integer` as its second.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Good point, I made a bad assumption there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your method to work with generics, it should be defined in the signature or in the class/interface definition.

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
    void addAThing(T thing);
    void addAListOfThings(Collection<T> things);
}
```

And the implementing class, of generic type `Foo`:

```
public class SomeInterfaceImplementation implements SomeInterface<Foo> {

    @Override
    public void addAThing(Foo thing) {
      // thing is of type Foo
    }

    @Override
    public void addAListOfThings(Collection<Foo> things) {
      // things is a collection of Foo
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel a bit silly. I've seen this in the past, but for some reason, I didn't recognize that I could use it in this particular case.

Comment: Nice. Pipped me with an exact dupe by 60 seconds.